# when two empty inline-blocks with different height are placed next to each other, the one with smaller height gets down a bit. why is that?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: red;
}
    
.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>
```

The smaller inline-block gets down a bit to get aligned with the larger inline-block. I don't know why this happens. I don't want it to happen.

(I know that the behaviour changes when some content is added to the empty divs)

jsfiddle-> https://jsfiddle.net/2vzjqreh/

Comment: Just to note that in your title you say that the smaller block 'gets some margin'. If you look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility you will see that it doesn't get a new margin. It is just positioned so as to align (at the bottom) with its neighbour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the vertical-align property, it's default value is 'baseline'. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). I've edited your code and just add `vertical-align` to
`.child-1` styles.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
    
.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks for the info!